# How to create custom dynamic query with paged results with JPA based on received parameters

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'd like to build a dynamic JPA query based on what parameters are received in my searach API endpoint, there 3 parameters possible: nome, cidade, causas (as an array that can have multiple numbers passed):

```
@GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<?> findByNome(Pageable pageable,
                                        @RequestParam Optional<String> nome,
                                    @RequestParam Optional<Long[]> causas,
                                    @RequestParam Optional<Long> cidade){
```

with these 3 parameters, there are 6 possible combinations of queries i need to use:
*only cidade passed
*cidade and causas
*only nome
*nome and causas
*cidade and nome
*cidade, nome and causas

To achieve the same currently i'm doing like this:

```
 @Repository
public interface InstituicaoRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Instituicao, Long> {

    //*only cidade passed
    Page<Instituicao> findByCidadeId(long cidadeId, Pageable pageable);
    //*cidade and causas
    @Query("select i from Instituicao i where i.cidadeId = ?1 and i.causaId in (?2)")
    Page<Instituicao> findByCidadeIdAndCausaIds(long cidadeId, Long[] causaIds, Pageable pageable);

    //*only nome
    Page<Instituicao> findByNomeContainingIgnoreCase(String nome, Pageable pageable);
    //*nome and causas
    @Query("select i from Instituicao i where lower(i.nome) like lower(concat('%',?1,'%')) and i.causaId in (?2)")
    Page<Instituicao> findByNomeAndCausaIds(String nomeInstituicao, Long[] causaIds, Pageable pageable);

    //*cidade and nome
    @Query("select i from Instituicao i where i.cidadeId = ?1 and lower(i.nome) like lower(concat('%',?2,'%'))")
    Page<Instituicao> findByCidadeIdAndNome(long cidadeId, String nomeInstituicao, Pageable pageable);
    //*cidade, nome and causas
    @Query("select i from Instituicao i where i.cidadeId = ?1 and lower(i.nome) like lower(concat('%',?2,'%')) and i.causaId in (?3)")
    Page<Instituicao> findByCidadeIdAndNomeAndCausaIds(long cidadeId, String nomeInstituicao, Long[] causaIds, Pageable pageable);

}
```

to invoke each InstituicaoRepository's method then i manually use ifs to check what parameters are and aren't present (which makes me wanna cry each time i look at my code)

Any suggestion on improving this to make it more efficient?
Please note that JPA's pagination needs to be included.

Comment: A trick is widely used adding `:param is null or ` with every condition then `and` them all. But I recommend spring jpa specification with a library details here https://blog.tratif.com/2017/11/23/effective-restful-search-api-in-spring/

Comment: hi, you can try use https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser . Good solution in this case. And you avoid this boilerplate query writing.

Comment: Automated Specification resolving solved my problem, many thanks

Comment: @sylleryum Welcome! I will try to write an answer with details whenever get time.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not good because you will have many method in your repository and it will grow by time, it is already mentioned in Spring.io itself, The better way to tackle this problem is using `Specification`, you can extend your repository from `JpaSpecificationExecutor` and pass the specification to be executed from other layers, it is cleaner and make your code easy to read. There is even a better way which is querydsl in which you even don't need to specify `Specification` and Spring data itself handle many situation for you. Read the following link from Spring itself:
[advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a library called [spring-dynamic-jpa](https://github.com/joutvhu/spring-dynamic-jpa) to make it easier to implement dynamic queries with JPA.

You can use it to write the query templates. The query template will be built into different query strings before execution depending on your parameters when you invoke the method.

```java
public interface InstituicaoRepository extends JpaRepository<Instituicao, Long> {
    @DynamicQuery("select i from Instituicao i\n" +
            "<@where>\n" +
            "   <#if cidadeId??>\n" +
            "       i.cidadeId = :cidadeId\n" +
            "   </#if>\n" +
            "   <#if nomeInstituicao??>\n" +
            "       and lower(i.nome) like lower(concat('%',:nomeInstituicao,'%'))\n" +
            "   </#if>\n" +
            "   <#if causaIds??>\n" +
            "       and i.causaId in :causaIds\n" +
            "   </#if>\n" +
            "</@where>")
    Page<Instituicao> findInstituicao(Long cidadeId, String nomeInstituicao, List<Long> causaIds, Pageable pageable);
}
```